# Directive inside directive link functions sync

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that manipulate Dom in the link function. Inside it another directive that I need its link function to be triggered after the parent directive finished its Dom manipulation. For example I assigned properties to the scope in the parent link function, but in the child directive the scope doesn't have those properties (scopes are not isolated and I need to modify the scope in the link function so I can access the element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For directives the order of execution of the `link` ( same as `post-link`) function is reversed. This means that for the following scenario :
`<span l1-dir><span l2-dir></span></span>`
The link function of the child directive is called first, and then the parent directive link is called. We are lucky because we also have the `pre-link` functions, which is called in the order of directive definition.
In our case the `pre-link` function of the first directive is called and then the the `pre-link` function of the second.
You can move the DOM manipulation logic from the parent directive in the `pre-link` function (first split into `pre` and `post`):

```
return {
        restrict: 'A', 
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {  //parent directive logic for DOM manipulation 
                },
                post: //nothing 
            }
        }
```

This ensures that in the `post-link` part of the child directive your DOM manipulation from the parent directive will be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an ng-if to your child directive, and set it to true after the completion of an $timeout at 0 in your "parent" directive, like this:

```
/*above should be placed all your parent directive link function code... the $timeout should be 
executed after your parent directive code*/
$timeout(function(){
    showChildDirective = "true";
}, 0);
```

this way, you'll perform all your task of your parent directive ($timeout will be placed on the bottom of the link function) and you'll be able to wait for the next $digest cycle to complete, 
so all your bindings to the DOM will be complete.